# Is it possible to write-protect files on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, file-permissions

I would like to prevent human error for some files on S3. I imagine something like

```
aws s3 chmod -w s3://my-bucket/some-important-file.txt
```

Is it possible to write-protect files on S3?

(I don't care if the user might easily find a way around. The important part is that it should be a cautious action. I want to prevent `aws cp local-file.txt s3://my-bucket/some-important-file.txt` and similar)

Answer (score 0):

No This is not supported at the moment. You could enable [versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-versioning.html) in your bucket, which will help protect your content from overwrites and accidental deletion. Note that this come with additional pricing.

Additionally you could [enable MFA delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete) to add another layer of security.